# How to return different Errors on a WebService Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I created a WebService Method where I check User login.
its just a `bool`

```
public bool CheckUserLogin(string user, string pass)
```

so it will return `true` or `false`.
The thing is that I built in different Error Handlings (wrong password, no db connection, etc.)

How can I return these ErrorMessages to the client back too ?

I tried creating a `Tuple` with 2 parameters (`bool`, `string`) but it started bugging.

Comment: What do you mean with `custom type` ?

Comment: Replace bool with a custom type (class) of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `CheckUserLogin` method is part of a Web API you could for example include a custom response message with an `HttpResponseException`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling.

If it's a WCF service method, you could throw a `FaultException` that contains the details of the error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.faultexception-1?view=netframework-4.7.1

Or/and you could change the return type of the method from `bool` to `YourType` where `YourType` is a serializable class that contains any possible error message along with the `bool` that indicates whether the authentication was successful. You can add several properties (information) to this class.

Comment: To create a custom return type worked for me thanks.